# Word to describe increase shareholding in something

Tags: terminology

Suppose Company Z had a 30% stake in Company A. Then, Company Z bought another 15% stake in Company A, bringing the total to 45%. I want to find a specific term for this situation.

I had initially considered:

- increased its stake
- increased its shareholding

But these seem a bit wordy, I'm after something that is one-word. Should the situation have been the opposite: Company Z sold 15% of Company A, we could use one word to explain the move: divest.

### Question

Is there any conventional financial term to explain the practice of a shareholder increasing its stake in a company in one word, or other professional term?

Comment: difficult to describe in one word other the to grow perhaps?

Comment: What's wrong with "invest"? It's the exact opposite of divest. Or if you want to emphasize that they're investing _again_, "reinvest"

Comment: “Increased its stake in” is the correct phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an antonym for divest, say that they're **investing**, or **reinvesting**.